# Custom Unique Row selection in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Let the table - TableA is as follows,

| Row_No | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | SER1 | Y | ABC |
| 2 | 1234 | SER2 | N | DEF |
| 3 | 3456 | SER1 | Y | XYZ |
| 4 | 3456 | SER2 | Y | PQR |
| 5 | 5678 | SER1 | N | QAZ |
| 6 | 5678 | SER2 | N | SRT |

Is it possible to get the result as shown below using oracle sql ?

| Row_No | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | SER1 | Y | ABC |
| 3 | 3456 | SER1 | Y | XYZ |
| 5 | 5678 | SER1 | N | QAZ |

The unique row selection rules are:

- Among rows with same value in COL1,

  - Select the row with Y for COL3. (For example, among rows: 1,2; 1st one has Y for COL3)
  - If both rows have same value(Y/N) for COL3 then select one of the row (among 3, 4 -> 3 & 5,6  -> 5 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *sort* rows using `row_number` analytic function and put named conditions into its `order by` clause, you'd get this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with tablea (row_no, col1, col2, col3, col4) as
  2    (select 1, 1234, 'SER1', 'Y', 'ABC' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 1234, 'SER2', 'N', 'DEF' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 3456, 'SER1', 'Y', 'XYZ' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 3456, 'SER2', 'Y', 'PQR' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 5678, 'SER1', 'N', 'QAZ' from dual union all
  7     select 6, 5678, 'SER2', 'N', 'SRT' from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select a.*,
 11       row_number() over (partition by col1
 12                          order by case when col3 = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end, row_no) rn
 13     from tablea a
 14    )
 15  select row_no, col1, col2, col3, col4
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1;

    ROW_NO       COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
---------- ---------- ---- ---- ----
         1       1234 SER1 Y    ABC
         3       3456 SER1 Y    XYZ
         5       5678 SER1 N    QAZ

SQL>
```